# convert a column to multiple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data with movie genres. the genres are separated with " "

```
id   genres
0   drama romance
1   drama
2   comedy
3   mystery thriller
4   crime thriller
...
```

And I want to split them by genres(about 20)

```
id   drama romance comedy...
0     1      1      0
1     1      0      0
2     0      0      1
3     0      0      0
4     0      0      0
...
```

I was thinking about getting dummies but I don't think it can help.

Comment: Take a look at `split`, `explode` and `crosstab` or `get_dummies`

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id'))` would be the simpliest solution imo.

Comment: Use `df.join(df.pop('text').str.get_dummies(' '))`

Comment: It looks like neither of the linked answers fully answers your question because your df contains a space separated list of genres.  Riccardo's answer is good. Both the other examples have multiple columns.  This should not have been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (`df` is your dataframe):

```
pd.merge(df[['id']], pd.get_dummies(df.genres.str.split().explode()),
         left_on='id', right_index=True).groupby('id').sum()
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0,1,2,3,4], 'genres': ['drama romance', 'drama', 'comedy', 'mystery thriller', 'crime thriller']})
>>> pd.merge(df[['id']], pd.get_dummies(df.genres.str.split().explode()), left_on='id', right_index=True).groupby('id').sum()
    comedy  crime  drama  mystery  romance  thriller
id                                                  
0        0      0      1        0        1         0
1        0      0      1        0        0         0
2        1      0      0        0        0         0
3        0      0      0        1        0         1
4        0      1      0        0        0         1
```